# How this could be a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Today in a textbook I have seen a exercise in which a set of following type was given

$A = \{a, \{b ,c\}\}$

How this could be a set when it contains two different type of elements like, one element is $a$ and other is a set of elements i.e. $\{b, c\}$. Isn't the set must contains same types of well defined elements?

Comment: In set-theory everything is a set. In this case: $a,b,c,\{b,c\},A$ are all sets that contain sets as elements. Actually there is no definition of set in set-theory. It is a primitive notion.

Comment: A set is a collection of "things". $\{apples,1,2,\int_cF\}$ is a set. In your case, you have a set, that contains $a$ (whatever that is maybe its a set itself?) and a set containing $b,c$

Comment: Even if you had $A=\{a,b\}$, how could you assure that $a$ and $b$ are of the same "type"? So there is no ambiguity here.

Comment: @Sorfosh: Wouldn't the construction of set builder form be difficult then? I mean if a set can contains randomly different types of objects then how can we generalize all the elements of set into a compact form?

Comment: @IgotiT You can't? Why is that a problem? A set is not an arcane, mysterious mathematical concept. It's a bunch of stuff. It can be a bunch of different stuff, that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

In *mathematics*, a set could be anything, as long as it's defined what is in it, and what's not.

You are probably confused because in most *programming languages* (such as c++, C# and java) when you create a *set* you need to have all the items at the same "type".

Answer (score 1):

In Axiomatic Set Theory, at least in the usual ZFC axioms, there is an axiom which states that for every two sets, there is a set whose elements are precisely those two sets. Since everything is a set, so is $a$ and $\{b,c\}$. Therefore the axiom says $\{a,\{b,c\}\}$ is a set.